# How to pass an input variable to PHP function without submitting form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have spent an entire day looking for answers and used Jquery in the code but it did not work.
I have a submit form with 2 buttons : submit, retrieve password

I want user to enter a username and click on retrieve password 
and then take that username and use it in php function to get user specific question from database and return it back 
in a text field

I am ok with the database part just need a simple example that works and passes username to php with click of retrieve password button 
without submitting the form or resetting the page that will lose all the information

Comment: maybe write an AJAX call?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it using jQuery like this:

```
<form>
    <input id="usernameInput" name="username" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<a id="RetrivePasswordBtn" href="#" data-url="http://www.example.com">
    Retrieve Password
</a>
```

And jQuery Code would go as:

```
<script>
    $(document).on(ready, function() {
        $("#usernameInput").on("input", function(e) {
            var url = $("#RetrivePasswordBtn").data("url");
            url += "?username=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
            $("#RetrivePasswordBtn").prop("href", url);
        })
    })
</script>
```

In PHP you would get it in GET Params like:

```
<?php
    function functionName() {
        // Here you can get the value of the username
        $username = $_GET('username');
    }
```

[View it in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bh1vjrh3/1/)

Hope this helps!

Or see the code block -

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
 $("#usernameInput").on("input", function(e) {
   var url = $("#RetrivePasswordBtn").data("url");
   url += "?username=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
   $("#RetrivePasswordBtn").prop("href", url);
      
      $("#textBlock").text(url);
 });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #1C90F3;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input id="usernameInput" name="username" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<a id="RetrivePasswordBtn" class="btn" href="#" data-url="http://www.example.com">
    Retrieve Password
</a>

<br /><br />
<div>
  Link to be created - <span id="textBlock"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I get the value with in PHP?

Comment: Wait, I am updating my answer!

Comment: thank you so much i am going to implement it now , hope it works.

Comment: @SeyedAliMojarrad - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: I will for sure once it works for me and I am sorry for taking a lot of your time. But the code does not seem to be working. 
the page i am running these codes on which I need to stay for rest of the process is called home.php  so given that I changed the data-url in html part to it and it still didnt work

Comment: Where you're getting stucked, is it the JS or PHP??

Comment: I have at the end of your function document.getElementById("ss").innerHTML= "<?php getQuestion(); ?> ";
where I can call a php function that echo $_GET['username']  but it does not change the value of the  ss txt

Comment: Sorry!, but I can't get you, please elaborate more to let me know your exact problem

Comment: I kept going over you code but I didnt see where exactly you posted the username, I see that you made it like a url link but how to post it actually so php can see it ?

Comment: Just click the link button `Retrieve Password`, it will take you to the specific PHP function (its all about routing in PHP, I think its common you should know it), and then inside the function you'll get the username in the GET params.

Comment: I see php function is called functionName() but where in retrieve password did you call that function ?